# Setup application arguments and to keep them in production?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, setup-project, shared-hosting, setup-deployment

In ASP.NET Core project I am using application arguments in development.

Something like that:

[image]

And that's working fine, but I would like to know which is the easiest setup to keep using these arguments in production, when deploying to a shared hosting?